# Powershell Add-NTFSAccess using csv

Tags: powershell, acl, ntfs

I'm a bit new to Powershell and i'm trying to complete a simple script for a project I'm working on. I get it working 95% of the way but it just not returning the results. I have loaded the NTFSSECURITY Module and I'm using Add-NTFSACCESS to set Deny delete on multiple folders using the paths stored in a .csv file. See below.

**Script**

```
$itempath = import-csv "C:\dox\folderpath.csv"
foreach ($items in  $itempath) {
    Add-NTFSAccess  -path $itempath -AccessRights Delete -Account "domain\username"  -AccessType Deny -AppliesTo ThisFolderOnly
}
```

This is the **error** i get

> Add-NTFSAccess : Unable to find the specified file.

Please help

Comment: `$itempath` is your collection. So you want to use `$items` for the path.

Answer (score 2):

`Add-NTFSAccess -path $itempath` this is telling powershell that the path to the item you want to change access to is an array of powershell objects that you imported from your CSV.  You'll need to change that to `$items.something` with "something" being the heading of the column in your CSV file that contains the path.

Answer (score 0):

OK Guys thanks a lot for your input. Its a simple script and what both of you said should work but I'm getting different errors. I found a way to do it without using a csv file but this was will apply the permission to all folders in the directory. Works for me. *Please not you have to import the NTFSSECURITY Module to use Add-NTFSAccess*

Get-ChildItem "\directory\path\" -Directory | % { $_.FullName} | Add-NTFSAccess  -AccessRights Delete -Account "domain\username" -AccessType Deny -AppliesTo ThisFolderOnly